# Why is this question closed even though it is very much technical and related to StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

My question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398875/getting-error-in-sitecore-after-installing-telligent-connect) titled `Getting error in Sitecore after Installing Telligent Connect` throwing some exceptions from web services of telligent (exception excerpts as below)

> [SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Int32. The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.]

**I don't think the statement for closing the question is apt and the question was very much technical and related to programming..**

> Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or
>   software development within the scope defined in the FAQ. Consider
>   editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you
>   believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope. Read
>   more about closed questions here.

I have voted to reopen the question.

My question here is
  1. What I can do (more) to reopen it?
  2. What is wrong in my question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398875/getting-error-in-sitecore-after-installing-telligent-connect) ?

Comment: Its off topic, not programming related

Comment: Too localized anyway by the look of the accepted answer.

Comment: Why _is_ this programming related? It appears you've got problems with an external sites functionality? You didn't build this site so you're asking about a product. Or am I completely wrong here?

Comment: The question is not about programming. It is also not about programming tools, as far as I can tell. It is about a specific issue you have in your installation of a piece of software.

Comment: And Can I know why my question on meta is being downvoted ? because I asked something on meta in which I am probably wrong and other user's question's [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91411/why-was-this-question-closed-as-off-topic-without-being-migrated?rq=1) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112902/why-was-my-question-about-the-term-to-describe-a-technical-concept-closed?rq=1) are upvoted because they are true in their standings..

Comment: @HarshBaid It all depends on how you approach the people here. In those cases, people agreed that the question should be re-opened or migrated as appropriate. In your case, people disagree with your premise.  Downvotes on meta generally convey disagreement with the substance or the style of the poster. You adamantly believe the SiteCore question is on topic, and the community disagrees with you.

Comment: I'm deleting this post and that also as it is localized I guess.

Comment: You won't be able to.

Comment: It is ok, I have flagged for moderator to delete the post.

Comment: We allow meta questions about specific questions. If we didn't, how would we build consensus around issues? Think local, act global is our mantra.

Answer (score 14):

I closed the question. I closed it because it's off topic for Stack Overflow (I'm not sure what site it'd be considered 'on topic' for, so I didn't migrate it).

SiteCore is a piece of software.  It clearly has a bug.  Neither of these are programming problems. If they were, there'd be so many Windows Blue Screen questions on Stack Overflow we'd forget there are other operating systems out there.

SiteCore is not used exclusively by programmers, nor is it a programmer's tool. It is a tool for creating content.  If this were on topic for Stack Overflow, then Wordpress bugs would be as well. They are not.

This question belongs on SiteCore's help forum.

Comment: I am developing site using Sitecore and it is an CMS tool. It is very much like Umbraco, DotNetNuke, **Orchard**, other similar ready to go sites. And it needs a developer to build a CMS which I am involved at the moment. I am feeling very bad at the moment I was facing issue since 3 days and no one was answering the question due to reason being it is related to some premium product and not an open source `Orchard CMS` (that I think of)

Comment: You are entirely missing the point though. This is not a development question, but a bug support one. That is outside the scope of SO and up to the official support channels.

Comment: @Bart, no, as per the FAQ: "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" is one of the questions you can ask, and the section of the FAQ on questions you can't ask does not say no "bug" questions.  __We do bugs.__

Comment: @LanceRoberts We do bug support for software? Come on. Even the answer given there indicates that this is ultimately a question that can only appropriately be handled by the creators of the software. This is not in SO's domain.

Comment: @Bart, programming software, but my comment wasn't referring to this question/answer, but to your overly broad comment.

Comment: So in this particular case my judgement is correct @LanceRoberts? Voting to reopen it, it seems you fundamentally disagree with that as well?